# Unable to do string comparison + post collection using wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

MY application consume a service and the service will send a list of questionaire to the client, on the UI when user ans the question the same data get assign to the model and send to the service for marking the score.

In the service i am doing an ID Check and a answer check (string) however despite it showing the same data type and value in the debugger the compare string is not return true. Can someone please guide me here thank.

```
public double GetMarks(List<Questionnaire> qList) {

        var AnsLibrary = GetAnswerLibrary();
        double GetTotalNumberAnsquestion = qList.Count();

        int numberValidCorrectAns = 0;
        double result  =0;
        try {
            if (GetTotalNumberAnsquestion > 0) {
                foreach (var q in qList) {

                    string city =(q.UserAnsResponse);

                    string compare = AnsLibrary.Where(x => x.Question.QuestionId == q.QuestionId).Select(x => new { name = x.AnswerText }).SingleOrDefault().ToString();

                    //just a test to see if the compare is working
                    if (string.Compare(city, AnsLibrary[0].AnswerText) == 0) {

                        //for testing purpose
                    }

                    bool isAnswerExist = AnsLibrary.Any(x => x.Question.QuestionId == q.QuestionId);
                    if (q.isCorrectAnswer == true) {

                        if (isAnswerExist && AnsLibrary.Any(a => a.AnswerText == city)) {
                            numberValidCorrectAns++;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        if (isAnswerExist && !AnsLibrary.Any(x => x.AnswerText == q.UserAnsResponse)) {
                            numberValidCorrectAns++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                result = numberValidCorrectAns / GetTotalNumberAnsquestion * 100;
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("Unable to get User Answer Questinaire");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
   public ViewResult GetMarks(List<QuestionnaireViewModel>  _AnswwerQuestionaire) {

           List<Questionnaire> serviceQuestionList = new List<Questionnaire>();

        foreach(var questionaire in _AnswwerQuestionaire){
            serviceQuestionList.Add(new Questionnaire() { QuestionId=questionaire.QuestionId, UserAnsResponse=questionaire.UserAnsResponse, isCorrectAnswer=questionaire.isCorrectAnswer});
        }

        var IQservice = new IQuestionService.QuestionServiceClient();
        var result = IQservice.GetMarks(serviceQuestionList);
        if(result > 0) {
        ViewData["Marks"] = result;
        } else {
        ViewData["Error"] = "Unable to Marks your assesment";
        }
        return View(result);
    }
```

Data Sample:

```
public static List<Answer> GetAnswerLibrary() {

        List<Answer> AnsLibrary = new List<Answer>();

        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 1, AnswerText = "London", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId= 11 } });
        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 2, AnswerText = "paris", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId = 22 } });
        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 3, AnswerText = "Warsaw", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId = 33 } });
        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 4, AnswerText = "Port louis", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId = 44 } });
        AnsLibrary.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 5, AnswerText = "Berlin", Question = new Questionnaire() { QuestionId = 55 } });

        return AnsLibrary;
    }
    //this is a hack normally will pull data from a data source like DB/CSV
    public static List<Questionnaire> GetQuestionLibrary() {
        List<Questionnaire> QuestionLibrary = new List<Questionnaire>();

        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(11) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of England", QuestionnaireType = 1 });
        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(22) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of France", QuestionnaireType = 1 });
        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(33) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of Poland", QuestionnaireType = 1 });
        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(44) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of Mauritius", QuestionnaireType = 1 });
        QuestionLibrary.Add(new Questionnaire(55) { Title = "Geo", QuestionAsk = "What is the capital of Germany", QuestionnaireType = 1 });

        return QuestionLibrary;
    }
```

Comment: One reason why it may not be working is you are "always" comparing your question's answer to first answer from answer set. i.e. string.Compare(city, AnsLibrary[0].AnswerText.  Here AnsLibrary's index is always 0.

Comment: i add these line only for testing purpose even if i remove these lines ///string compare = AnsLibrary.Where(x => x.Question.QuestionId == q.QuestionId).Select(x => new { name = x.AnswerText }).SingleOrDefault().ToString();

                    //just a test to see if the compare is working
                    if (string.Compare(city, AnsLibrary[0].AnswerText) == 0) {

                        //for testing purpose
                    } // it still not working

Comment: Very basic question. Did you check in debugger that "city" and "AnsLibrary[0].AnswerText" has same values?

Comment: i did same data type and same value

Comment: string.Compair uses current culture to obtain culture-specific information e.g. how upper case and lower case it compaired. I suggest you use overload of string.Compair to ignore case sensetive comparision. You can try if(string.compair(city, AnsLibrary[0].AnswerText,true)==0). Pay attention to third param.

Answer (score 0):

i manage to solve this problem, below is the modification i did. It kind of a weird.

```
 public double GetMarks(List<Questionnaire> qList) {

        var AnsLibrary = GetAnswerLibrary();

        double result = 0;
        double TotalNumberofQuestion = qList.Count();
        int UserValidAnswer = 0;

        if(TotalNumberofQuestion >0) {

            var filterQuestionaire = qList.Where(q => q.UserAnsResponse != null).ToList();

            foreach (var q2 in filterQuestionaire) {


                bool checkOnlyAnswerQuestion = AnsLibrary.Any(x => x.Question.QuestionId == q2.QuestionId);

                if(checkOnlyAnswerQuestion) {

                string city = (q2.UserAnsResponse).Trim();
                string city2 = AnsLibrary.Where(x => x.Question.QuestionId == q2.QuestionId).Select(t => t.AnswerText).SingleOrDefault().Trim();

                    bool checkuserAnswer = (city == city2) ;

                    if(q2.isCorrectAnswer == true && checkuserAnswer == true){
                        UserValidAnswer++;
                    }

                    if(q2.isCorrectAnswer == false && checkuserAnswer == false) {

                        UserValidAnswer++;
                    }
                }
            }
            result = UserValidAnswer / TotalNumberofQuestion * 100;
        }
        return result;
    }
```